# Python pandas: Adding a new column where each row depends on earlier rows

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having some trouble figuring out how I can add new columns whose entries refer to multiple other rows of the same dataframe.

Input dataframe:

```
Date        Player1ID  Player2ID  WinnerID  
2018-06-10  a          b          a
2018-06-11  b          c          b
2018-06-12  c          a          a
2018-06-13  b          a          a
2018-06-14  b          b          c
2018-06-15  a          c          c
2018-06-16  b          c          b
2018-06-17  a          c          a
2018-06-18  b          a          a
...
```

Context: Rows of this dataframe are outcomes of a sport match. I want to create two columns which, at each date, show the "present form" of player 1 and player 2. For a simple start, I want to use the number of games in their last N games (N=2 in the example below) that each player has won.

For example, on 2018-06-13, player 2 (the player with ID '1') was in good form - they won both of their previous two games on 2018-06-12 and 2018-06-10. So for that date, the form indicator p2_Num_wins_last2 is set as 1.

Desired output dataframe:

```
Date        Player1ID  Player2ID  WinnerID  p1_Num_wins_last2  p2_Num_wins_last2
2018-06-10  a          b          a         -                  -    
2018-06-11  b          c          b         -                  -
2018-06-12  c          a          a         -                  -
2018-06-13  b          a          a         1                  2
2018-06-14  3          b          c         0                  1
2018-06-15  a          c          c         2                  1
2018-06-16  b          c          b         0                  2
2018-06-17  a          c          a         1                  1
2018-06-18  b          a          a         1                  1
...
```

I am trying to use the lapply function with reference to some sub-dataframe above the original eg.

```
df["p1_Num_wins_last2"] = df.lapply(lambda row: func(row,subDataFrame))
```

but am having a really hard time making it work. Need to generalise this to many many players and lots of dates and a more general number of N games.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear what you want, in your desired output, why is `p1_Num_wins_last2` on `2018-06-14` set to `0`? Player 1 won all 3 match up prior to that. Why are there `2` in the column? what is it supposed to mean?

Comment: You're looking for [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) and its [apply function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply.html). Rolling lets you create a rolling window of some size and gives you what's called a `rolling object`. That object has an apply function that basically gets handed a DataFrame for each window and otherwise functions like a normal apply.

Comment: @RockyLi Sorry that was my bad labelling. I've now changed the player IDs to be characters rather than numbers.. p1_Num_wins_last2 is referring to whoever the player is in position "Player1ID"